# Exchange Powershell Questions

Tags: powershell, exchange

Goal: Find all mailboxes which have not sent (or received possibly?) mail in the past 90 days.

I've seen a few guides on powershell commands but I'm not positive I have the right order (Get-Mailbox | etc) so I don't want to risk executing it?

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  What have you tried?  You really should try to reduce the scope of this question.

Comment: @Abraxas Good question. Exchange Server Version?

Comment: @STTR Thanks. We're on Exchange 2010 in an AD environment on Server 2012 R2. Let me know if you need anything else.

Ramhound - I haven't tried anything because I am not confident in my understanding of PowerShell yet. My question is what is a way to use PS to get a listing of mailboxes which have not sent and/or received email in the past 90 days (possibly export to a csv?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add-pssnapin *exchange* -EA 0
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited |Get-MailboxStatistics |?{$_.Lastlogontime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)}|Select DisplayName, LastLoggedOnUserAccount, LastLogonTime |Export-csv .\NotAccess90.csv -noType
```

Way 2: Log Exchange to SQL Server Express edition.

This is a way to create quick reporting. Only need to create indexes fields that will be searched. Then the query processing speed will be about 1-3 M records per second. That is the speed of file creation - will not be as fast. Ideal job done through the driver csv. In general, the improvement infinitely).

## But, stop log (SQL Server Express) - Exchange Server stop too!

Need sql function:

ConvertCharIP - convert string IP address to BIGINT

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertCharIP] (@IP AS VARCHAR(20)) 
RETURNS BIGINT 
AS 
BEGIN 
RETURN (CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IP,1)) + 
         CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IP,2)) * 256 + 
         CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IP,3)) * 65536 + 
         CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IP,4)) * 16777216)    
END
```

ConvertLongIP - convert BIGINT to string IP address.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertLongIP] (@LongIP bigint)

RETURNS varchar(15) AS BEGIN 
DECLARE @DotIP varchar(15), @bin varbinary(4) 
select @bin = cast(@LongIP as varbinary(4)) 

select @DotIP = cast(convert(int,substring(@bin,1,1)) as varchar(3)) 
+ '.' + cast(convert(int,substring(@bin,2,1)) as varchar(3)) 
+ '.' + cast(convert(int,substring(@bin,3,1)) as varchar(3)) 
+ '.' + cast(convert(int,substring(@bin,4,1)) as varchar(3)) 

RETURN @DotIP END
```

getCurrentTime - return now time.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getCurrentTime]() 
RETURNS DATETIME 
AS  
BEGIN  
    RETURN (SELECT CurrentTime FROM CurrentDateTime)  
END
```

Use pattern:

MailAddress.sql:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(bytesrecvd)/1024 AS [Upload, Kb],
   SUM(bytessent)/1024 AS [Download, Kb],
   ...
   <other log column name>,
   master.[dbo].[ConvertLongIP]([SourceIP]) AS [SourceIP],
   master.[dbo].[ConvertLongIP]([DestinationIP]) AS [DestinationIP]

 FROM [<Table name>]

WHERE
<other bound>
AND master.[dbo].[ConvertLongIP]([SourceIP])=@DotIP

GROUP BY [SourceIP],[DestinationIP]

SourcePort
,DestinationPort

ORDER BY [Upload, Kb] DESC
```

QueryMail.cmd:

```
@echo off
SET SQLSERVER=.\SQL2K5
SET DBName=Exch2010
SET QueryFile=MailAddress.sql
SET CSVLog=C:\MailLogCSV

@echo %date% %time%
sqlcmd -S %SQLSERVER% -d %DBName% -E -h-1 -i %QueryFile% -o %CSVLog%\MailAddress-%DBName%.csv -s ";" -W
@echo %date% %time%
```

Comment: @Abraxas If you need to more accurately handle logs mail, do not rely on the Exchange service's tracking.http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/exhange_server_2010-smtp_logs,2-214-2.html

Comment: @Abraxas Update.